# Get the percentage true of a boolean column in Snowflake SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there a function in Snowflake SQL to get the percentage of a boolean column?

For instance, if my data were to look like this:

| id | category | boolean |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | true |
| 2 | a | false |

I would like to use something like [RATIO_TO_REPORT()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/ratio_to_report.html) to get:

| category | pct |
| --- | --- |
| a | 0.50 |

One thought is to create a numerical column from boolean in a CTE, then use it to generate a pct, however, I have a lot of data, so am wondering if there is a faster way (i.e. some native sql function or approach I am missing).

Additionally, I would like to solve for categories with more than 1 grouping column (e.g. category2) and more than 1 boolean column (e.g. boolean2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Count conditionally and divide by the total count:

```
select category, count_if(boolean) / count(*)
from mytable
group by category
order by category;
```